# To be friend / on good terms with / to etc

Tags: prepositions

Imagine a mother who notices that her son has had a problem with one of his classmates who the mother knows him / her well. She wants to discover if they are on good terms / are friends yet or they have broken up. Which one of the prepositions below in the self-made sentences of mine doesn't sounds natural to you:

> - Are you two still on good terms / friends ***to* each other**?
> - Are you two still on good terms / friends ***with* each other**?
> - Are you two still on good terms / friends **together**?
> - Are you two still on good terms / friends ***with* one another**?

For me, they all work, but I doubt if native speakers think so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full idiomatic expression is **(to be) on good terms (with somebody)**, therefore the first and third expressions don't work particularly well. A similar argument can be made for **friends** - one can '***be*** a good friend **to** somebody', but one '***is*** friends **with** somebody'.

> Are you two still on good terms / friends with each other?
>
> Are you two still on good terms / friends with one another?

Both are acceptable. Or the 'with each another/with one another' can be omitted entirely, if it is implicit in the conversation who the other person is. For example:

> A: Have you seen John recently?
>
> B: Yes, I saw him yesterday.
>
> A: Are you still on good terms?

Comment: I'd add that the _with one another_ version sounds more formal than _with each other._ I doubt I'd use the former in conversation.